# Docking controls to points

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my WP7App the user can drag a rectangle arround, it should dock on a grid columns and row crosses. Is there a guid how to do that. Its my first game, usually i do database stuff.

I use for dragging arround OnDragDelta, is there a drop/leave/exit event?

Or like in windows forms dragenter / dragleave events?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned OnDragDelta, I assume you are using the GestureListener class from the Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit.

If this is the case, you also have a DragStarted and DragCompleted events you can use!